# In JScript, why can't I use the enumerator or Keys of a HashTable?

Tags: .net, hashtable, jscript, enumerator

This is JScript, not JavaScript.

I have a `System.Collections.Hashtable` object. I want to get all the keys in it.

I can grab an enumerator to that object:

`var benumbing = event1.GetEnumerator();`

but when I call [MoveNext()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Hashtable_GetEnumerator) on the object, I get this error:

`Attempt by method 'invoker11.Invoke(System.Object, System.Object[])' to access type 'System.Collections.Hashtable+HashtableEnumerator' failed.`

I can also grab the `Keys` property, and can call the `GetType()` method on it to see that is a `System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection`, but if I access the `Count` member of it, I get the error

`Attempt by method 'invoker8.Invoke(System.Object, System.Object[])' to access type 'System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection' failed.`

It feels like OO-protection levels are not correct somehow. Is there some method to declaring my hashtable object?